# Display Default Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I uploaded image via paperclip so it's uploaded then after I will remove that image manually so now in our table entry is there that image is uploaded but in our system that image is not found. because we remove that image manually. In this case I want to display a default image if image is uploaded on server but not present in server.

My Image is stored in Amazon

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I Fix that issue by using following code

```
require "net/http"
url = URI.parse( image_path )
req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
begin
  res = req.request_head(url.path)
rescue     
end
```

Hope, This will help you in you feature